# Angular 4 rerouting loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have angular 4 application.
Routes:

```
appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ContentComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'country/:country',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ContentComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'category/:category',
        component: ContentComponent
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

It's currently just a work in progress, so I'm displaying same component in all routes.

Now, if I go to the root path '/' it works just fine. However, if I go to '/country/us' path or even '/country/us/category/sales', the page loads some parts then goes all white, checking the console, I see the routing events are occurring over and over and over, just as if every time the route loads, it reloads again on the same route. Additionally I see this error:

```
zone.js:196 Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.
    at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:2577:15)
    at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:3188:3)
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.FUNCTION (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:2554:10)
    at Object.eval (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:2557:2)
    at Object.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:5380:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:55:30)
    at Object.../../../../../src/polyfills.ts (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:12:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:55:30)
    at Object.1 (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:5387:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:55:30)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong there??

Edit 1:
There also seems to be a problem in the routes, the paramMap has no keys in there.

Comment: Why did you use jquery? Does it affect the zone loaded? The same things doesn't compile on the different zone. Make sure you have one zone loaded for each script.

Comment: I actually have no idea where jquery is being used, the only script references I have are in the index page where I put the <app-root>
other components and their templates shouldn't be loading any other scripts.

Also, is this problem related to infinite routing loop?

Answer (score 0):

```js
appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ContentComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'country/:country',component: ContentComponent
    children: [
      {
        path: 'category/:category',
        component: ContentComponent
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

Comment: When posting code to answer a question on SO, please include a description that explains how the code solves the problem.